# How to globally add a class to an input field on focus in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Say I have two components **A-Component** and **B-Component**.Both of these contains some form-fields.When a text field is `focused` I would like to add a `css class` to its parent. I know its possible to add a focus event for the text field or by using a directive.

```
<input name="date" type="text" (focus)="focusFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()">
```

But rather than using `focus event` or `directive` for every text fields, is there a possibility to write something **globally** for every component so that it effects all the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
 <div class="parentDiv" ng-class="{'classOnFocus': focusClass}">
       <input name="date" type="text" ng-focus="focusClass = true" ng-blur="focusClass = false">
 </div>
```

Similar thing you can do on all fields

Comment: Tanx for the reply.I was thinking rather than complicating the template is there some way by which I could handle this. The html would get a bit messy since I have a lot of fields.I was thinking if it would be possible to handle it in the root level.

Comment: syntax should be `[ngClass]="{'classOnFocus': focusClass}"` right?

Answer (score 0):

You can write css class in `style.css` file.`style.css` file applied global style for angular app

Comment: Tats not what the question is bro